# trouble importing stanford pos tagger into nltk

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

This is probably a very trivial question. I am trying to use the stanford pos tagger through nltk given [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordTagger-class.html) The problem is that my nltk lib doesnt contain the stanford module. So I copied the same into the appropriate folder and compiled the same. Now when i try to run an example the module is getting detected but not the class inside the module. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?? Again this is probably very dumb.

```
>>> from nltk.tag import stanford 
>>> st = StanfordTagger('bidirection-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger')
```

I used py_compile to compile the stanford.py file. Am i missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only importing `stanford`. In order to access `StanfordTagger` you need to use either:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordTagger
```

(assuming that `StanfordTagger is not further nested in a module) or access it by

```
>>> st = stanford.StanfordTagger('bidirection-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger')
```

Comment: OMG yeah how did i forget that!! Will need to figure out this other error though.

Comment: Did you compile the `nltk/tag` directory _and_ the `nltk/internals` directory? I have never needed to use py_compile, python has always handled it for me automatically, so my knowledge is somewhat limited here.

Comment: This is really a seperate question from the first one. By changing the contents of the question so it no longer explains your initial problem, and is no longer helpful to future users. Please (at minimum) include the initial question.

Comment: yeah i am sorry, i did realize it only now.. will change

Comment: I get TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class StanfordTagger with abstract methods _cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Stanford parser, use this:

```
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = '/folder/with/standford/jars'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/folder/with/standford/jars'

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="/location/of/the/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
print parser.raw_batch_parse(("Hello, My name is Melroy.", "What is your name?"))
```

Output:

> [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('INTJ', [Tree('UH', ['Hello'])]),
>   Tree(',', [',']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['My']), Tree('NN',
>   ['name'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('ADJP', [Tree('JJ',
>   ['Melroy'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])]), Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SBARQ',
>   [Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WP', ['What'])]), Tree('SQ', [Tree('VBZ',
>   ['is']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['your']), Tree('NN', ['name'])])]),
>   Tree('.', ['?'])])])]

**Note 1:**
In this example both the parser & model jars are in the same folder.

**Note 2:**

- File name of stanford parser is: stanford-parser.jar
- File name of stanford models is: stanford-parser-x.x.x-models.jar

**Note 3:**
The englishPCFG.ser.gz file can be found inside the models.jar file (/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz). Please use come archive manager to 'unzip' the models.jar file.