# How can I get the stanford NLTK python module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nltk

I have the `python` (2.7.5) and `python-nltk` packages installed in Ubuntu 13.10. Running `apt-cache policy python-nltk` returns:

```
python-nltk:
  Installed: 2.0~b9-0ubuntu4
```

And according to the [Stanford site](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), 2.0+ should have the `stanford` module. Yet when I try to import it, I get an error:

```
>>> import nltk.tag.stanford
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stanford
```

How can I get the stanford module? (Preferably through the usual repositories, since I don't like to install software outside the Ubuntu package manager.)

Comment: hi! have you looked at this other related question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8555312/583834. also, i just created a virtualenv on a mac, did `pip install nltk` and `import nltk.tag.stanford` worked without doing `nltk.download()`. having said that, i have no idea where the needed files (namely `/usr/share/stanford-ner/classifiers/all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz` and `/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar`) are...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use NLTK downloader:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```