# how to parse text in nltk using stanford nlp?

Tags: java, python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have parsed text using stanford nlp java, but now i want to parse the text by integrating Stanford nlp in nltk, please help me what are the steps to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This may answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk

Comment: I already gone through that link, i dint understand the procedure from those answers, thats why i am asking again, can u please explain me the steps