# Instead writing nlp stanford chinese segmenter output to std output, want it in some List or String

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on chinese language segmentation part. For that I am using Stanford Segmenter http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml.
This code writing output to screen but I want to store it in some list or string. Please help how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stanford Parser and NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk)

Comment: if you need to code in other languages other than python, there should be similar way of piping terminal outputs into your code.