# Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) functionality with NLTK

Tags: location, nltk, named-entity-recognition

Is this possible: to get (similar to) Stanford Named Entity Recognizer functionality using just NLTK?

Is there any example?

In particular, I am interested in extraction LOCATION part of text. For example, from text

> The meeting will be held at 22 West Westin st., South Carolina, 12345
>   on Nov.-18

ideally I would like to get something like

```
(S  
22/LOCATION
(LOCATION West/LOCATION Westin/LOCATION)
st./LOCATION
,/,
(South/LOCATION Carolina/LOCATION)
,/,
12345/LOCATION
```

.....

or simply

```
22 West Westin st., South Carolina, 12345
```

Instead, I am only able to get

```
(S
  The/DT
  meeting/NN
  will/MD
  be/VB
  held/VBN
  at/IN
  22/CD
  (LOCATION West/NNP Westin/NNP)
  st./NNP
  ,/,
  (GPE South/NNP Carolina/NNP)
  ,/,
  12345/CD
  on/IN
  Nov.-18/-NONE-)
```

Note that if I enter my text into  http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process I get results far from perfect (street number and zip code are still missing) but at least "st." is a part of LOCATION and South Carolina is a LOCATION and not some "GPE / NNP" : ?

What I am doing wrong please? how can I fix it to use NLTK for extracting location piece from some text please?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19):

nltk **DOES** have an interface for Stanford NER, check [`nltk.tag.stanford.NERTagger`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html?highlight=stanford#nltk.tag.stanford.NERTagger).

```py
from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
st = NERTagger('/usr/share/stanford-ner/classifiers/all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
               '/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar') 
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

output:

```
[('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'),
('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'),
('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'LOCATION')]
```

However every time you call `tag`, nltk simply writes the target sentence into a file and runs Stanford NER command line tool to parse that file and finally parses the output back to python. Therefore the overhead of loading classifiers (around 1 min for me every time) is unavoidable.

If that's a problem, use [Pyner](https://github.com/dat/pyner).

First run Stanford NER as a server

```
java -mx1000m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer \
-loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -port 9191
```

then go to `pyner` folder

```py
import ner
tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=9191)
tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
# {'LOCATION': ['California', 'United States'],
# 'ORGANIZATION': ['University of California']}
tagger.json_entities("Alice went to the Museum of Natural History.")
#'{"ORGANIZATION": ["Museum of Natural History"], "PERSON": ["Alice"]}'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know if I can train Stanford NER and how? I tried it with. "Wizard of Oz leaves Emerald City." and "Alexander the Great conquered Empire of Persia." Neither worked.

Comment: @edfward the java runs it on port 9191 but the python runs it on port 8080. Why is that?

Comment: @akh2103 my fault. I've corrected in the answer, they should be consistent while the actual port may vary.

Comment: for those who get empty set of entities (`{}`) from pyner, [here is the solution](https://github.com/dat/pyner/issues/2#issuecomment-51715087): `tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=xxxx, output_format='slashTags')`