# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' for Geniatagger?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to perform chunking using geniatagger in python, which requires to be downloaded using git clone.

Using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078901/genia-tagger-file-not-found-error-in-anaconda-nltk), I downloaded and installed geniatagger and imported in my application.

However, when I try accessing parse functionality, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-867eea8ac07f> in <module>
      1 my_bytes = "This is a pen.".encode()
      2 print(type(my_bytes))
----> 3 x = tagger.parse(my_bytes)

~/anaconda3/envs/systreviewclassifi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geniatagger_python-0.1-py3.6.egg/geniatagger.py in parse(self, text)
     33         results = list()
     34 
---> 35         for oneline in text.split('\n'):
     36             self._tagger.stdin.write(oneline+'\n')
     37             while True:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This is the code, I tried.

```
tagger = GeniaTagger('./geniatagger/geniatagger')
# option1: my_bytes = "This is a pen.".encode()
# option2: my_bytes = b"This is a pen."
# option3: my_bytes = bytes("This is a pen.")
my_bytes = "This is a pen.".encode('utf8')
print(type(my_bytes))
x = tagger.parse(my_bytes)
```

Currently, I get the above-given error as output. Technically, this should be the output.

```
>>> print tagger.parse('This is a pen.')
[('This', 'This', 'DT', 'B-NP', 'O'), ('is', 'be', 'VBZ', 'B-VP', 'O'), ('a', 'a', 'DT', 'B-NP', 'O'), ('pen', 'pen', 'NN', 'I-NP', 'O'), ('.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O')]
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code is not fully `Python 3` compatible.

You pass in a string encoded as bytes, but on [line 35](https://github.com/informationsea/geniatagger-python/blob/master/geniatagger.py#L35) (`for oneline in text.split('\n')`) the variable `text` is of type bytes but the argument to `.split()` (`'\n'`) is a string. That causes the error.

You can reproduce the error in your interpreter like this:

```
>>> 'asdasd'.encode().split('d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

---

You can try to input a string instead of bytes in `tagger.parse()`, but no idea if that is going to work.

Comment: On passing it as a string, it returns this error again. "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'. I felt it was shady too since split is executed on a string.