# Stanford parser doesn't work with python (Windows 7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use this solution [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk), but it just cannot work. This is basically calling Stanford parser from python and then getting the output in the python. The parser is written in java.

```
import os
sentence =  '''I shot an elephant in my pajamas'''
os.popen("echo '"+sentence+"' > ~/stanfordtemp.txt")
parser_out = os.popen("C:/Python27/stanford-parser-2012-11-12/lexparser.sh   ~/stanfordtemp.txt").readlines()
print parser_out
```

It works strange because when the patch isn't correct it doesn't report an error and when the patch to the software is correct windows asks in which program do i want to open the application. After i do that i am still getting just the blank output as before. Maybe this has something to do with me running windows 7 and not Unix?

```
Update: Tried to install CoreNLP and I cannot ... the file location is accurate.
corenlp = StanfordCoreNLP(corenlp_dir)  # wait a few minutes...
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\corenlp\corenlp.py", line 430, in __init__
self._spawn_corenlp()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\corenlp\corenlp.py", line 399, in _spawn_corenlp
self.corenlp = pexpect.spawn(self.start_corenlp, timeout=60, maxread=8192,   searchwindowsize=80)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\pexpect.py", line 429, in __init__
self._spawn (command, args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\pexpect.py", line 516, in _spawn
raise ExceptionPexpect ('The command was not found or was not executable: %s.' % self.command)
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: java.
Exception AttributeError: "StanfordCoreNLP instance has no attribute 'corenlp'" in    <bound method StanfordCoreNLP.__del__ of <corenlp.corenlp.StanfordCoreNLP instance at  0x021DDA08>> ignored

Exception AttributeError: "StanfordCoreNLP instance has no attribute 'corenlp'" in <bound method StanfordCoreNLP.__del__ of <corenlp.corenlp.StanfordCoreNLP instance at 0x0228DA08>> ignored
```

Comment: This is because you probably don't have Bash shell installed. .sh files are for  unix style shells.

Comment: So what exact software should i install? There is nothing named exactlyBash shell?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Cygwin comes with the bash shell, though that's a bit overkill. MinGW also has bash.

Comment: I tried to install it but stopped because the downloading of the scripts took so long. How large is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to use the Stanford NLP parser, I'd take the easy route and follow these instructions.

https://bitbucket.org/torotoki/corenlp-python

Once you throw up the NLP parser as a server (note that default port is 8080), open another python session and type in the following.

Just tried it and it works well :-)

```
import jsonrpclib
import json

server = jsonrpclib.Server("http://localhost:8080")

result = json.loads(server.parse("What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"))
print result
```

This is the printout:

{u'sentences': [{u'parsetree': u'(ROOT (SBARQ (WHNP (WP What)) (SQ (VBZ is) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN airspeed) (NN velocity)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT an) (JJ unladen)))) (VP (VB swallow))) (. ?)))', u'text': u'What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?', u'dependencies': [[u'root', u'ROOT', u'swallow'], [u'dobj', u'swallow', u'What'], [u'aux', u'swallow', u'is'], [u'det', u'velocity', u'the'], [u'nn', u'velocity', u'airspeed'], [u'nsubj', u'swallow', u'velocity'], [u'det', u'unladen', u'an'], [u'prep_of', u'velocity', u'unladen']], u'words': [[u'What', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'4', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'0', u'PartOfSpeech': u'WP', u'Lemma': u'what'}], [u'is', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'7', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'5', u'PartOfSpeech': u'VBZ', u'Lemma': u'be'}], [u'the', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'11', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'8', u'PartOfSpeech': u'DT', u'Lemma': u'the'}], [u'airspeed', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'20', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'12', u'PartOfSpeech': u'NN', u'Lemma': u'airspeed'}], [u'velocity', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'29', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'21', u'PartOfSpeech': u'NN', u'Lemma': u'velocity'}], [u'of', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'32', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'30', u'PartOfSpeech': u'IN', u'Lemma': u'of'}], [u'an', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'35', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'33', u'PartOfSpeech': u'DT', u'Lemma': u'a'}], [u'unladen', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'43', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'36', u'PartOfSpeech': u'JJ', u'Lemma': u'unladen'}], [u'swallow', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'51', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'44', u'PartOfSpeech': u'VB', u'Lemma': u'swallow'}], [u'?', {u'NamedEntityTag': u'O', u'CharacterOffsetEnd': u'52', u'CharacterOffsetBegin': u'51', u'PartOfSpeech': u'.', u'Lemma': u'?'}]], u'indexeddependencies': [[u'root', u'ROOT-0', u'swallow-9'], [u'dobj', u'swallow-9', u'What-1'], [u'aux', u'swallow-9', u'is-2'], [u'det', u'velocity-5', u'the-3'], [u'nn', u'velocity-5', u'airspeed-4'], [u'nsubj', u'swallow-9', u'velocity-5'], [u'det', u'unladen-8', u'an-7'], [u'prep_of', u'velocity-5', u'unladen-8']]}]}

Comment: Why do you call it easy route? If i am not missing something, this things cannot be installed on windows 7 because the requied pexpect module doesn't work on any windows. On which is did you install it?

Comment: Try this [link] (https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/archive/master.zip) :)

(Note: I am using OS X on a Mac Mini, sorry, missed you were using Windows 7. You may be right that it is not possible.)

Comment: Tried to install and it it is only supports unix like OS's. Anyway i am going to try it with Cygwin

Comment: I have found wexpect and before that i have installed pywin32. Worked better but i still have an error.

Comment: I did the install as in the URL except these command: git clone https://bitbucket.org/torotoki/corenlp-python.git
  cd corenlp-python
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2013-11-12.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2013-11-12.zip

Comment: So i manually installed CoreNLP in  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\corenlp and copied the stanford CoreNLP there. Is this ok?

Comment: Should be. Read the "README". I ran everything from the corenlp-python directory rather than the corenlp subdirectory: "python corenlp\corenlp.py" with the stanford-corenlp-full-2013-11-12 directory in the corenlp-python directory. @Brana