# Parse English sentences using nltk

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, context-free-grammar

I am parsing English sentences using NLTK library. Every time i parse a sentence i provide grammar specific to that sentence e.g. if need to parse

```
I shot an elephant in my pajamas
```

I will provide grammar something like this

```
 grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""
 S -> NP VP
 PP -> P NP
 NP -> Det N | Det N PP | 'I'
 VP -> V NP | VP PP
 Det -> 'an' | 'my'
 N -> 'elephant' | 'pajamas'
 V -> 'shot'
 P -> 'in'
 """)
```

Above grammar includes non terminals which are specific to this sentence only. Is there  any grammar which can works for every sentence? [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) do this thing. Can we get the grammar used by Stanford Parser for this purpose
Also what will you recommend nltk or Stanford Parser.
Thanks

Comment: Please add language tags where applicable: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179544/tagging-the-language-when-only-the-library-is-tagged

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/14376410#14376410