# Error using Stanford POS Tagger in NLTK Python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to use Stanford POS Tagger in NLTK but I am not able to run the example code given here http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
st = POSTagger(r'english-bidirectional-distim.tagger',r'D:/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar')
st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow?'.split())
```

I have already added environment variables as

```
CLASSPATH = D:/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar
STANFORD_MODELS =  D:/stanford-postagger/models/
```

Here is the error I keep getting

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:\pos_stanford.py", line 4, in <module>
    st = POSTagger(r'english-bidirectional-distim.tagger',
         r'D:/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar')  
... LookupError: NLTK was unable to find the english-bidirectional-distim.tagger file! Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the STANFORD_MODELS environment variable.
```

Some forums suggest that

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 45, in __init__
env_vars=('STANFORD_MODELS'), verbose=verbose)
```

should be changed so that there is a comma in

```
env_vars=('STANFORD_MODELS',), verbose=verbose)
```

but it doesn't solve the problem either. 
Please Help me in solving this issue.

Other Information:
I am using
Windows 7 64 bit
Python 2.7 32 bit
NLTK 2.0

Comment: I noticed you're using forward slashes (/) in your environment paths - on Windows it should be back slashes (\). Also, try running it from the same directory as your models to avoid path issues.

Comment: I tried using backslashes too.
didn't work.

Comment: Also tried changing the directories and all but no use

Comment: Try unpacking the models jar and make sure you have the `english-bidirectional-distim.tagger` file in path `STANFORD_MODELS\edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\english-bidirectional\ ` where `STANFORD_MODELS` is defined or is your script's CWD

Comment: @jkoreska: Incorrect, Windows has been allowing forward-slashes since at least 2003. Forward-slashes are preferred in Python since you don't get into escaping and raw-strings (r'')

Comment: @smci yea thanks now I feel old :/

Comment: @jkoreska No worries, I couldn't believe it myself when my friend told me several years ago. Microsoft certainly added this change quietly... almost surrendering to UNIX's convention on '\'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note : Just posting it as answer to help in case others face this issue in future

I finally found out what I did wrong.. it turned out to be a blunder.

Tagger file name  is not 'english-bidirectional-distim.tagger'
but 'english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'.