# Stanford NER Tagger super slow

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to process a text file of 1M lines. Each string is one line, and I need to obtain location information from each string. The easiest way I thought of doing so was using Stanford's NER tagger in PYTHON.

However, the tagger is performing extremely slow, like 2 seconds per line. By this speed it will take 20 days to complete my file. Also its somewhat inaccurate, missing obvious locations like "nyc".

Anyone know how I can speed things up a little and make it more accurate?

Thanks

Comment: Stanford Core NLP is Java. How are you calling it from python?

Comment: There is an interface that allows python to access it

from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

Comment: How fast is it in Java?

Comment: Not very fast, but who knows? You need to test it on your own data.

Comment: Same speed as Python? Like 2 seconds per line...? I would test it, but I have to setup all the java stuff. Troublesome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23322996/610569

Comment: Why are you testing tagging speed per sentence? You should be testing it per corpus with `tag_sents()`.

Comment: Im not testing tagging speed per sentence. My file is 1million lines, I need to extract LOCATION information from each line. And so far its not working.