# Stanford Entity Recognizer (caseless) in Python Nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to figure out how to use the caseless version of the entity recognizer from NLTK. I downloaded http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip and placed it in the site-packages folder of python. Then I downloaded http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-caseless-2015-04-20-models.jar and placed it in the folder. Then I ran this code in NLTK

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
english_nertagger = NERTagger(‘/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz’, ‘/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-corenlp-caseless-2015-04-20-models.jar’)
```

But when I run this:

```
english_nertagger.tag(‘Rami Eid is studying at stony brook university in NY’.split())
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier
```

Any help if you have experience is appreciated!

P.S. I can get the non-caseless version working fine but I find that when analysing search queries, users hardly ever capitalize words and the non-caseless version appears to completely miss words if they are not capitalized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second parameter of `StanfordNERTagger` is the path to the stanford tagger jar file, not the path to the model. So, change it to `stanford-ner.jar` (and place it there, of course).

Also it seems that you should choose  `english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz` (from stanford-corenlp-caseless-2015-04-20-models.jar) instead of `english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz`

Thus try the following:

```
 english_nertagger = StanfordNERTagger(‘/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers/english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz’, ‘/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner.jar’)
```

Upd. `NERTagger` has been renamed to `StanfordNERTagger`

Comment: Now `NERTagger` is not available in `nltk.tag.stanford`, Instead  `StanfordNERTagger` is available. If you update your answer it's very helpful.

Comment: I must be blind, I don't see `english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz` in the classifier folder of the `2015-04-20` download