# NLTK: why does nltk not recognize the CLASSPATH variable for stanford-ner?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

This is my code

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
```

And i get

```
NLTK was unable to find stanford-ner.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.
```

This is what my `.bashrc` looks like in ubuntu

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/wolfgang/Downloads/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar
export STANFORD_MODELS=/home/wolfgang/Downloads/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/classifiers
```

Also, i tried printing the environmental variable in python this way

```
import os
os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')
```

And i recieve

```
'/home/wolfgang/Downloads/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar'
```

Therefore the variables are being SET!

What is wrong then?

Why doe'snt nltk recognize my environmental variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34112695/610569

Answer (score 6):

change the .jar file and the environmental variable from `stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar` to `stanford-ner.jar`

apparently NLTK has a `name_pattern` variable in `nltk_internals.py` which only accepts the CLASSPATH if it matches a regex of the value `stanford-ner.jar`

Comment: or you could simply set the classpath to the parent folder too like `os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "/home/wolfgang/Downloads/stanford-ner-2015-04-20"`. Both these options(parent folder or stanford-ner.jar) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to set PATH:

```
st = StanfordNERTagger('C:\Python26\Lib\stanford-ner\classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','C:\Python26\Lib\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar')
```

Give the correct path to locate both file. If there is still a Java Environment variable error, then it means your Java Environment is not configured. To set this, go to 'My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Setting'. There are videos showing what these settings do. Once you've done this, if the environment is properly set then  when you run the python file a black command window will splash for around ten seconds while it processes your file. This should return your result without error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
import os

os.getenv('CLASSPATH')
```

OUTPUT: '/home/user/Downloads/stanford-ner.jar'

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger("english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz")
```

Download **stanford-ner.jar** from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/stanford/stanford-postagger.jar.zip)

Set Classpath `export CLASSPATH=/home/admin-pc/Downloads/`

**Worked For Me :p**