# Unable to instantiate StanfordNERTagger on OS X

Tags: python, nltk, osx-yosemite, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to instantiate **`StanfordNERTagger`**. This is what I am trying:

```
st = StanfordNERTagger("/Users/attitude/Desktop/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz","/Users/attitude/Desktop/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar")
```

I have set the `CLASSPATH` variable to `/Users/attitude/Desktop/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar` (I also tried just the parent folder as value - `/Users/attitude/Desktop/stanford-ner-2015-12-09`).

However, I am getting this error:

`LookupError: Could not find stanford-ner.jar jar file at /Users/attitude/Desktop/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar`.

I have done everything mentioned in these two answers - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819573/nltk-why-does-nltk-not-recognize-the-classpath-variable-for-stanford-ner) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652725/importerror-cannot-import-name-stanfordnertagger-in-nltk). What else do I do now to fix this error?

OS X Yosemite - Python 2.7.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34112695/610569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

Without setting environmental variable, use the keywords arguments, `model_filename` and `path_to_jar`

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

stanford_ner_dir = '/home/alvas/stanford-ner/'
eng_model_filename= stanford_ner_dir + 'classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
my_path_to_jar= stanford_ner_dir + 'stanford-ner.jar'

st = StanfordNERTagger(model_filename=eng_model_filename, path_to_jar=my_path_to_jar) 
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

---

**In long:**

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112695/610569