# Error when running Stanford Dependency Parser

Tags: python, windows, parsing, stanford-nlp

I already follow all the instructions in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software, [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053021/stanford-dependency-parser-setup-and-nltk). But still got some errors.

Here is my codes:

```
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
java_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\bin\\java.exe'
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = 'C:/Users/stanford/stanford/stanford-parser.jar'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = 'C:/Users/stanford/stanford/stanford-parser-3.6.0-models.jar'

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="C:/Users/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents(("Hello, My name is Melroy.", "What is your name?"))
print sentences

# GUI
for line in sentences:
    for sentence in line:
    sentence.draw()
```

Error received:

```
raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))

OSError: Java command failed :
```

I already updated nltk, installed all the stanford parser jar files. I use python 2.7, windows 7.

Comment: As far as I understand from links you provided, `STANFORD_PARSER` and `STANFORD_MODELS` should point to directory with `.jar` files, in your case `'C:/Users/stanford/stanford'`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. but i still received the same error.