# nltk StanfordNERTagger : NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory (In Windows)

Tags: python, windows, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

NOTE: I am using Python 2.7 as part of Anaconda distribution. I hope this is not a problem for nltk 3.1.

I am trying to use nltk for NER as

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger 
#st = StanfordNERTagger('stanford-ner/all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
print st.tag(str)
```

but i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:41)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1117)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1076)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1057)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3088)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\jnk.py", line 47, in <module>
    print st.tag(str)
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 66, in tag
    return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), []) 
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 89, in tag_sents
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "X:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 134, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['X:\\PROGRA~1\\Java\\JDK18~1.0_6\\bin\\java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'X:\\stanford\\stanford-ner.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier', '-loadClassifier', 'X:\\stanford\\classifiers\\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', '-textFile', 'x:\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqjsoma', '-outputFormat', 'slashTags', '-tokenizerFactory', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer', '-tokenizerOptions', '"tokenizeNLs=false"', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

but i can see that the slf4j jar is there in my lib folder. do i need to update an environment variable?

**Edit**

Thanks everyone for their help, but i still get the same error. Here is what i tried recently

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger 
print(nltk.__version__)
stanford_ner_dir = 'X:\\stanford\\'
eng_model_filename= stanford_ner_dir + 'classifiers\\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
my_path_to_jar= stanford_ner_dir + 'stanford-ner.jar'
st = StanfordNERTagger(model_filename=eng_model_filename, path_to_jar=my_path_to_jar) 
print st._stanford_model
print st._stanford_jar

st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

and also

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger 
print(nltk.__version__)
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
print st._stanford_model
print st._stanford_jar
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

i get

```
3.1
X:\stanford\classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
X:\stanford\stanford-ner.jar
```

after that it goes on to print the same stacktrace as before. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`

any idea why this might be happening? I updated my CLASSPATH as well. I even added all the relevant folders to my PATH environment variable.for example the folder where i unzipped the stanford jars, the place where i unzipped slf4j and even the lib folder inside the stanford folder. i have no idea why this is happening :(

**Could it be windows? i have had problems with windows paths before**

**Update**

1. The Stanford NER version i have is 3.6.0. The zip file says `stanford-ner-2015-12-09.zip`
2. I also tried using the `stanford-ner-3.6.0.jar` instead of `stanford-ner.jar` but still get the same error
3. When i right click on the `stanford-ner-3.6.0.jar`, i notice

[image: jar properties]

**i see this for all the files that i have extracted, even the slf4j files.could this be causing the problem?**

4. Finally, why does the error message say

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`

i do not see any folder named `org` anywhere

**Update: Env variables**

Here are my env variables

```
CLASSPATH
.;
X:\jre1.8.0_60\lib\rt.jar;
X:\stanford\stanford-ner-3.6.0.jar;
X:\stanford\stanford-ner.jar;
X:\stanford\lib\slf4j-simple.jar;
X:\stanford\lib\slf4j-api.jar;
X:\slf4j\slf4j-1.7.13\slf4j-1.7.13\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar

STANFORD_MODELS
X:\stanford\classifiers

JAVA_HOME
X:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_6

PATH
X:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\bin;
X:\stanford;
X:\stanford\lib;
X:\slf4j\slf4j-1.7.13\slf4j-1.7.13
```

anything wrong here?

Comment: when I ran your sample script I got the error """Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.""" so yes, I would assume you need to update it

Comment: classpath is already pointing to the folder where stanford stuff has been unzipped. i am wondering if i should also add the path to the lib folder in classpath

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford if you haven't checked that out yet

Comment: yup thats where i got the sample code from

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695

Comment: The lib folder needs to be in the CLASSPATH as well.

Comment: @AbtPst, did you get this to work? I'm facing the same problem on Mac OS X El Capitan. First it gave me `UnsupportedClassVersionError` which made me to upgrade java 7 to 8, then it gives me this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## EDITED

**Note:** The following answer will only work on:

- NLTK version 3.1
- Stanford Tools compiled since 2015-04-20

As both tools changes rather quickly and the API might look very different 3-6 months later. Please treat the following answer as temporal and not an eternal fix.

Always refer to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software for the latest instruction on how to interface Stanford NLP tools using NLTK!!

---

## Step 1

First update your NLTK to the version 3.1 using

```
pip install -U nltk
```

or (for Windows) download the latest NLTK using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

Then check that you have version 3.1 using:

```
python3 -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)"
```

## Step 2

Then download the zip file from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip and unzip the file and save to `C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\` (In windows)

## Step 3

Then set the environment variable for `CLASSPATH` to `C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar`

and the environment variable for `STANFORD_MODELS` to 
`C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\classifiers`

Or in command line (**ONLY for Windows**):

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar
set STANFORD_MODELS=%STANFORD_MODELS%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\classifiers
```

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176423/610569 for click-click GUI instructions for setting environment variables in Windows)

(See [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695) for details on setting environment variables in Linux)

## Step 4

Then in python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
>>> st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
>>> st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
[(u'Rami', u'PERSON'), (u'Eid', u'PERSON'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'studying', u'O'), (u'at', u'O'), (u'Stony', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Brook', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'University', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'NY', u'O')]
```

Without setting the environment variables, you can try:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

stanford_ner_dir = 'C:\\some\path\to\stanford-ner\'
eng_model_filename= stanford_ner_dir + 'classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
my_path_to_jar= stanford_ner_dir + 'stanford-ner.jar'

st = StanfordNERTagger(model_filename=eng_model_filename, path_to_jar=my_path_to_jar) 
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

See more detailed instructions on [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i tried your approach but i still get the error. please see the edit

Comment: Have you tried `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar` and `set STANFORD_MODELS=%STANFORD_MODELS%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\classifiers`

Comment: yes i have set up both of the env variables correctly. please see the edit as i have noticed other behavior as well.

Comment: please see the edit, i have added details about my env variables

Comment: Can you run this on your windows command line: `X:\\PROGRA~1\\Java\\JDK18~1.0_6\\bin\\java.exe -mx1000m -cp X:\\stanford\\stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier X:\\stanford\\classifiers\\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile x:\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqjsoma -outputFormat slashTags -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerOptions "tokenizeNLs=false" -encoding utf8` ?

Comment: same error ! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Comment: Yeah, it's a java thing. maybe it needs additional classpath in windows. Let me check.

Comment: Short question, did you use http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip?

Comment: For quick fix, use http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip. I'll try to update an answer for 2015-12-09 in a while.

Comment: that works! thanks a lot :) but i think its a bit dangerous that it only works for a certain version of stanford ner ! also, i am using python 2.7. could that be causing a problem?

Comment: When using stanford-ner-2015-04-20, it will work for both python2.7 and python3. But it's a catch up game of NLTK catching up with Stanford's API.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try it with python 3.x as well, maybe it will work there. please try to get a solution for 2015-12-09, if thats possible. i will accept your answer anyway.

Comment: No problem =) It will take a while to correct the NLTK API, meanwhile please use the 2015-04-20 or try using the Stanford CoreNLP with jsonlib, e.g. http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~dm303/stanford-dependency-parser-nltk-and-anaconda.html

Answer (score 4):

I encountered exactly the same problem as you described yesterday.

There are 3 things you need to do.

**1) Update your NLTK.**

```
pip install -U nltk
```

Your version should be >3.1 
and I see you are using

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
```

However, you gotta use the new module:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
```

**2) Download slf4j and update your CLASSPATH.**

Here is how you update your CLASSPATH.

```
javapath = "/Users/aerin/Downloads/stanford-ner-2014-06-16/stanford-ner.jar:/Users/aerin/java/slf4j-1.7.13/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar"
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = javapath
```

As you see above, the javapath contains 2 paths, one is where stanford-ner.jar is, the other is where you downloaded slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar (It can be downloaded here: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

**3) Don't forget to specify where you downloaded 'english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz' & 'stanford-ner.jar'**

```
st = StanfordNERTagger('/Users/aerin/Downloads/stanford-ner-2014-06-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','/Users/aerin/Downloads/stanford-ner-2014-06-16/stanford-ner.jar') 

st.tag("Doneyo lab did such an awesome job!".split())
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i tried your approach but i still get the error. please see the edit

Comment: please see the edit, i have added details about my env variables.

Comment: thanks for your help @doneyo, but it looks like the problem was with the stanford ner version i was using.

Comment: @AbtPst Have you tried "2015-01-30" version, instead of 10-days-ago version? January version won't throw slf4j/LoggerFactory error.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:**

Below is a temporal hack to work with:

- NLTK version 3.1
- Stanford NER compiled on 2015-12-09

This solution is **NOT** meant to be an eternal solution.

Always refer to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software for the latest instruction on how to interface Stanford NLP tools using NLTK!!

Please track updates on this issue if you do not want to use this "hack": https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1237 or please use the NER tool compield on 2015-04-20.

---

## In Short

Make sure that you have:

- NLTK version 3.1
- Stanford NER compiled on 2015-12-09
- Set the environment variables for `CLASSPATH` and `STANFORD_MODELS`

To set environment variables in Windows:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\stanford-ner.jar
set STANFORD_MODELS=%STANFORD_MODELS%;C:\some\path\to\stanford-ner\classifiers
```

To set environment variables in Linux:

```
export STANFORDTOOLSDIR=/home/some/path/to/stanfordtools/
export CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar
export STANFORD_MODELS=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers
```

Then:

```
>>> from nltk.internals import find_jars_within_path
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
>>> st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
# Note this is where your stanford_jar is saved.
# We are accessing the environment variables you've 
# set through the NLTK API.
>>> print st._stanford_jar
/home/alvas/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar
>>> stanford_dir = st._stanford_jar.rpartition("\\")[0] # windows
# Note in linux you do this instead: 
>>> stanford_dir = st._stanford_jar.rpartition('/')[0] # linux
# Use the `find_jars_within_path` function to get all the
# jar files out from stanford NER tool under the libs/ dir.
>>> stanford_jars = find_jars_within_path(stanford_dir)
# Put the jars back into the `stanford_jar` classpath.
>>> st._stanford_jar = ':'.join(stanford_jars) # linux
>>> st._stanford_jar = ';'.join(stanford_jars) # windows
>>> st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
[(u'Rami', u'PERSON'), (u'Eid', u'PERSON'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'studying', u'O'), (u'at', u'O'), (u'Stony', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Brook', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'University', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'NY', u'O')]
```

Answer (score 2):

i fixed!

u should indicate the **full path** of slf4j-api.jar in CLASSPATH

instead of add jar-path into system environment variable, u can do like this in code:

```
_CLASS_PATH = "."    
if os.environ.get('CLASSPATH') is not None:
    _CLASS_PATH = os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = _CLASS_PATH + ';F:\Python\Lib\slf4j\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar'
```

**important**, in nltk/*/stanford.py will **reset** the classpath like this:

```
stdout, stderr = java(cmd, classpath=self._stanford_jar, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

eg. \Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\stanford.py line:90

u can fix it like this:

```
_CLASS_PATH = "."
if os.environ.get('CLASSPATH') is not None:
    _CLASS_PATH = os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')
stdout, stderr = java(cmd, classpath=(self._stanford_jar, _CLASS_PATH), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Current Stanford NER tagger version is not compatible with `nltk` because it requires additional jars that `nltk` cannot add to the `CLASSPATH`.

Instead prefer an older version of Stanford NER Tagger that will works perfectly fine like this one: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-04-20.zip

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to use Stanford NER >= 3.6.0 instead of the 2015-01-30 (3.5.1) or other old version, do this instead:

1. Put the stanford-ner.jar and slf4j-api.jar into the **same folder**

   For example, I put the following files to **/path-to-libs/**

   - stanford-ner-3.6.0.jar
   - slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar
2. Then:

   ```
   classpath = "/path-to-libs/*"

   st = nltk.tag.StanfordNERTagger(
       "/path-to-model/ner-model.ser.gz",
       "/path-to-libs/stanford-ner-3.6.0.jar"
   )
   st._stanford_jar = classpath
   result = st.tag(["Hello"])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with how `slf4j` has been used.

I am on nltk 3.1 and using `stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09`. I only way I could get it to work was to modify `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py` and add the `slf4j` jar to `self._classpath` within `init` method.

That solved it. Crude - but - works.

Note - I was not trying NER exactly. I was trying something like below

```
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = '/Users/run2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/Users/run2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09'
parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path='/Users/run2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/englishPCFG.ser.gz')
sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents('<some sentence from my corpus>')
```

Comment: No - that does not work because stanford.py hard codes the class path jars

Comment: Try the "hack" from here: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1239#issuecomment-167224937

Comment: That's not true, you can overwrite the jar paths by editing the `st._stanford_jar`. Look at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/stanford.py#L50 that's the line that added the jar files. Which NLTK version are you using?

Comment: Here's a more StanfordNERTagger specific solution: https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Comment: hi alvas - as mentioned earlier I am using nltk 3.1. Well - yes - you can do it lots of ways (once you are editing that file which is what I did). For me editing line 64 seemed more logical. self._classpath = (stanford_jar, model_jar, '/Users/run2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/slf4j-api.jar')

Answer (score 0):

According to me the `java environment` is not set for python in your code.

You could do that by using the following code:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
import os
java_path = "/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
st = NERTagger('../ner-model.ser.gz','../stanford-ner.jar')
tagging = st.tag(text.split())
```

Check if this solves your problem.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. Because if java isn't initialized properly, the Java Exception would not have appeared.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is simply to download the latest version of the Stanford NER tagger where the dependency problem is now fixed (March 2018).

```
wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2018-02-27.zip
```