# Error in Stanford Pos Tagger

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

Hello i am trying to do POS tag for a certain sentence using Stanford Pos Tagger. I am using Python 3.4 nltk 3.1 on windows7
Following is the code i used:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
import os
java_path = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

St=POSTagger(r"C:\Python34\Scripts\stanford-postagger-2015-12-09\models\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger",r"C:\Python34\Scripts\stanford-postagger-2015-12-09\stanford-postagger.jar")

tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("Sample for tagging a sentence.")
print(St.tag(tokens))
```

Yet, i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Loading default properties from tagger C:\Python34\Scripts\stanford-postagger-2015-12-09\models\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:42)

at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:146)

at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:128)

at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1836)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

... 4 more

File "C:\Users\workspace\src\chunking.py", line 15, in <module>
print(St.tag(tokens))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 59, in tag
return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 81, in tag_sents stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 160, in java     raise OSError('Java command failed!')
OSError: Java command failed!
```

Please can anyone help me solve the error?

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1304

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nltk StanfordNERTagger : NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory (In Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361725/nltk-stanfordnertagger-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-in-windo)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding two more jar files two your build path. You will find these files in the lib folder of the downloaded package `slf4j-api.jar` and `slf4j-simple.jar`.
Have a look into [this tutorial](https://rajvardhan.wordpress.com/tag/stanford-pos-tagger/)

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem so i downloaded another version of POS tagger the stanford-postagger-full-2014-08-27. It is working now.