# Stanford POS tagger Python 3 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

```
>>>import nltk
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
>>> st = StanfordPOSTagger('/home/psycho/anaconda3/pkgs/nltk-3.1-py35_0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger','/home/psycho/anaconda3/pkgs/nltk-3.1-py35_0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford-postagger.jar')
>>>st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

But i get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>         at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.(IOUtils.java:42)
>         at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.(TaggerConfig.java:146)
>         at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.(TaggerConfig.java:128)
>         at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1836)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 4 more
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line
> ```
>
> 66, in tag
>           return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), []) 
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line
>   89, in tag_sents
>           stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 134, in java
>           raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
>       OSError: Java command failed : ['/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', '/home/psycho/nltk_data/taggers/stanford-postagger.jar',
>   'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model',
>   '/home/psycho/nltk_data/taggers/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger',
>   '-textFile', '/tmp/tmprn3miqjh', '-tokenize', 'false',
>   '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf8']

How do I solve it?
I have the latest version of Java

Comment: did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361725/nltk-stanfordnertagger-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-in-windo ?