# NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar! Set the CLASSPATH environment variable

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am working on a project that requires me to tag tokens using nltk and python. So I wanted to use this. But came up with a few problems.
I went through a lot of other already asked questions and other forums but I was still unable to get a soultion to this problem.
The problem is when I try to execute the following:

---

`from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
 st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')`

---

I get the following:

---

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    `File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
        st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')`

    `File "C:\Users\MY3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.1-py3.5.egg\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 131, in __init__
        super(StanfordPOSTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

    `File "C:\Users\MY3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.1-py3.5.egg\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 53, in __init__
        verbose=verbose)`

     `File "C:\Users\MY3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.1-py3.5.egg\nltk\internals.py", line 652, in find_jar
        searchpath, url, verbose, is_regex))`

     `File "C:\Users\MY3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.1-py3.5.egg\nltk\internals.py", line 647, in find_jar_iter
        raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))`

    LookupError: 

    ===========================================================================
      NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
      environment variable.

    ===========================================================================
```

I already set the 
CLASSPATH - `C:\Users\MY3\Desktop\nltk\stanford\stanford-postagger.jar`
I tried it as `C:\Users\MY3\Desktop\nltk\stanford` as well..

STANFORD_MODELS - `C:\Users\MY3\Desktop\nltk\stanford\models\`

I tried doing this as well..in vain
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 45, in __init__
env_vars=('STANFORD_MODELS',), verbose=verbose)`
but it doesn't solve the problem either. Please Help me in solving this issue.

I use Windows 8, python 3.5 and nltk 3.1

Comment: Have you tried looking in the jar file and models directory for english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger?

Comment: Please try solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/27415031/610569 or https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7/17176423#17176423

Comment: I smell windows: https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9 *"Please please please understand the solution don't just copy and paste!!! We're not monkeys typing Shakespeare ;P"*

Answer (score 26):

### Update

The original answer was written for **Stanford POS Tagger Version 3.6.0, Date 2015-12-09**

There is a **[new Version (3.7.0, released 2016-10-31)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#History)**. Here's the code for the newer version:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Add the jar and model via their path (instead of setting environment variables):
jar = 'your_path/stanford-postagger-full-2016-10-31/stanford-postagger.jar'
model = 'your_path/stanford-postagger-full-2016-10-31/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger'

pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar, encoding='utf8')

text = pos_tagger.tag(word_tokenize("What's the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?"))
print(text)
```

---

### Original answer

I had the same problem (but using OS X and PyCharm), finally got it to work. Here's what I've pieced together from the [StanfordPOSTagger Documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordPOSTagger) and [alvas' work on the issue](https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a) (big thanks!):

```
from nltk.internals import find_jars_within_path
from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Alternatively to setting the CLASSPATH add the jar and model via their path:
jar = '/Users/nischi/PycharmProjects/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger.jar'
model = '/Users/nischi/PycharmProjects/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger'

pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar)

# Add other jars from Stanford directory
stanford_dir = pos_tagger._stanford_jar.rpartition('/')[0]
stanford_jars = find_jars_within_path(stanford_dir)
pos_tagger._stanford_jar = ':'.join(stanford_jars)

text = pos_tagger.tag(word_tokenize("What's the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?"))
print(text)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @rima in PyCharm you can set the environment variables via Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Environment: Environment Variables -> [...] -> [+]

Comment: Good job understanding the solution =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695

Answer (score 1):

I use Jupyter Notebook with Pycharm.
I tried the Run Configuration in Pycharm to set env variable, but not work.
So I use os.environ to set it in the code:

```
import os

os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = "/yourPath/stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17:yourPath/stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16:yourPath/stanford-ner-2018-10-16"
os.environ["STANFORD_MODELS"] = "yourPath/stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16/models:yourPath/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers"

stanford_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')
```

Hope it will help!