# NLTK was unable to find the java file! for Stanford POS Tagger

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have been stuck trying to get the Stanford POS Tagger to work for a while. From an [old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726200/nltk-was-unable-to-find-stanford-postagger-jar-set-the-classpath-environment-va) I found the following (slightly modified) code:

```
stanford_dir = 'C:/Users/.../stanford-postagger-2017-06-09/'

from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
#from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger # I tried it both ways
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Add the jar and model via their path (instead of setting environment variables):
jar = stanford_dir + 'stanford-postagger.jar'
model = stanford_dir + 'models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger'

pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar, encoding='utf8')

text = pos_tagger.tag(word_tokenize("What's the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?"))
print(text)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

I don't know what java file it is talking about. I'm sure it's finding the right files because if I change the path to something incorrect I get a different error:

```
LookupError: Could not find stanford-postagger.jar jar file at C:/Users/.../stanford-postagger-2017-06-09/sstanford-postagger.jar
```

What java file is missing? How do I get the Stanford POS tagger to work?

EDIT:

I went to this [link for Stanford NLP on Windows](https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9) and tried:

(Second EDIT - adding the installation procedures):

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile
urllib.request.urlretrieve(r'http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20.zip', r'C:/Users/HMISYS/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20.zip')
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:/Users/HMISYS/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20.zip')
zfile.extractall(r'C:/Users/HMISYS/Downloads/')
# End second edit

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
# Trying on an older version
_model_filename = r'C:/Users/HMISYS/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'
_path_to_jar = r'C:/Users/HMISYS/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20/stanford-postagger.jar'
st = StanfordPOSTagger(model_filename=_model_filename, path_to_jar=_path_to_jar)
text = st.tag(nltk.word_tokenize("What's the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?"))
print(text)
```

but I got the same error. Based on [this post](https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a) I set my path variables with the following:

```
set STANFORDTOOLSDIR=$HOME
set CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20/stanford-postagger.jar
set export STANFORD_MODELS=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20/models
```

But I get this error:

```
NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar! Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.
```

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: Specifically, see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9#step-5b-install-stanford-ner-the-cheater-way

Comment: Did you install as per the instructions on the github gist?

Comment: Yes, and I edited my question to include those procedures.

Comment: I don't believe Windows recognizes variables in the form `$HOME`. Try a little harder, and check that `CLASSPATH` has _exactly_ the intended content. Look _carefully_ at the result of `ECHO %CLASSPATH%`.

Answer (score 20):

I added the following lines to my code and it worked:

```
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```