# NLTK API to Stanford POSTagger works fine for ipython in terminal but not working in Anaconda with spyder

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded stanford postagger and parser following the instructions written for below question:

[Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695)

But when I execute the commands at bottom, it worked perfectly fine for ipython in terminal (Mac OS) but showed error in Spyder(Anaconda) 
(NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar!) Since I have set `CLASSPATH` in terminal, I am not sure what went wrong. When I checked

```
import os
print os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')
```

It returned `None` in Spyder but correct path in terminal. I have also restarted the program and set directory to `$HOME`. Is there anything I might be missing here?

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')
st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with python or the nltk; it's a consequence of how OS X starts GUI applications. Basically, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set in your `.profile` or its kin, but this file is only executed when you are starting Terminal; GUI applications inherit their environment from your login process, which doesn't know `CLASSPATH`.

There are numerous SO questions about how to deal with this; see [here](https://superuser.com/q/476752/127080) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x). But in your case, there are also a couple of work-arounds that ought to work:

1. Start Spyder from the Terminal command line, not via the Launchpad (just type `spyder &`). Or
2. Your python program can also set its own environment (which will be inherited by child processes) prior to launching the Stanford parser, like this:

   ```
   os.putenv("CLASSPATH", "/path/to/the/parser")
   ```

Comment: I just started spyder from terminal and it worked perfectly. also appreciate the education about why this happened and the additional readings as well.

Comment: @CWlearner, please do accept the answer (with the checkmark) if alexis' answer resolves your problem.