# Python NLTK Setting up environmental variables - Windpws

Tags: python, environment-variables, nltk, stanford-nlp

Currently, I need to setup the environment variables such that NLTK can find the relevant file path to my downloaded Stanford module package automatically.

Windows 8.1, I go to System properties > Advanced > environment variables, but I'm not sure what I'm doing here is correct. I have the needed Stanford files downloaded in a folder on my desktop, and tried to setup the environment variables to go to its path, but it doesn't work.

An image of the environment variables is here: [What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWXmF.png)

Anyone know how to set this up correctly and then test if it is working? Been following this guide to little success: [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/34112695#34112695)

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a

Comment: On linux/mac using environment variables is easy, using it windows is a mess of configurations. So on windows, set the path within your code.

Comment: See also: https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9