# nltk problems with Stanford NLP

Tags: python, jar, nltk, stanford-nlp

New to Python 3.6 with Mac...Was trying to use NLTK with Stanford NLP.

(1) was totally not able to understand environment variables and can't set correctly when using Stanford NLP. I tried the following but run out of idea when arriving at STEP3,

> Add the appropriate Stanford NLP .jar file to the  CLASSPATH environment variable.

[Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/)

Wondering whether some guys can explain patiently how the CLASSPATH works and how to set them with/before NLTK (export codes are disabled in NLTK)

Although setting environment variables is a much elegant way, I have to choose the alternative. I downloaded all jar files and put them on my desktop. (No idea where they should be placed. Most related instructions deals with Windows, which does not work for Mac).

Therefore, tried to specify the locations of Stanford NLP tools, such as follows

[screenshot of the codes and how they failed in the interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cy3D.png)

Hope to solve it! Thanks much!!!!

Comment: export CLASSPATH='path/to/.filejar'

Comment: Please add errors as text inside the question (preferably inside a code box) rather than using pictures.

Comment: the body text does not allow for "". I delete them and the warning still there...can't solve

Comment: BTW, Python 3.6 is not officially supported.

Comment: Did you go through all the links in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112695/610569 Don't be lazy, reading the answers carefully without copy+paste will help you understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To set an environment variable globally, run

```
export CLASSPATH="path/to/file.jar"
```

from the terminal (iTerm or iTerm2 on mac) or

```
export CLASSPATH=`pwd`/file.jar
```

if you're in the folder where file.jar is located.

To set an environment variable in a python script:

```
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = 'path/to/file.jar'
```

Note that in a python script, the values will not be availabile after that script has run.

Comment: Thanks. I have been confused with the "path".. Is this a full path or its a path in some particular formatts.

Comment: absolute path. starts with /