# nltk StanfordNERTagger is not working

Tags: python, nltk

Here is the python code :

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('D:/stanford-ner-2018-02-27/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
           'D:/stanford-ner-2018-02-27/stanford-ner.jar')

r=st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
print(r)
```

My all absolute paths are correct. I also have set JAVA_HOME environment variables. But I am facing these errors.

```
C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe E:/WorkStation/untitled1/a.py
C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py:183: DeprecationWarning: 
The StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 3.2.5.
Please use nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPPOSTagger or nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPNERTagger instead.
  super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/WorkStation/untitled1/a.py", line 6, in <module>
    r=st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 84, in tag
    return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), [])
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 89, in tag_sents
    config_java(options=self.java_options, verbose=False)
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 58, in config_java
    _java_bin = find_binary('java', bin, env_vars=['JAVAHOME', 'JAVA_HOME'], verbose=verbose, binary_names=['java.exe'])
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 604, in find_binary
    binary_names, url, verbose))
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 598, in find_binary_iter
    url, verbose):
  File "C:\Users\Yunus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 569, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anybody find me a solution please ?

python 3.6.2 (64 bit version)
jdk 1.8.0_61

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345866/610569

Comment: Yes this is duplicate. Cause I was trying the same code and got error. But no solution could be found in google . Thanks Alvas. I am looking to the answer. If not I will knock again.

Comment: Read the answer carefully. Hope it helps.