# Running stanford ner tagger in pycharm is not working

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am new to pycharm professional ide, python and nltk.
i want to use stanfordNertagger for my project work. When I use the following code in python file in pycharm professional

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stanford_classifier = '/home/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/stanford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
stanford_ner_path = '/home/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/stanford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar'

# Creating Tagger Object
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')

text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print classified_text
```

The error shown is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/premchikkus/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/premchikkus/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 168, in __init__
    super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/premchikkus/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 53, in __init__
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/premchikkus/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 719, in find_jar
    searchpath, url, verbose, is_regex))
  File "/home/premchikkus/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 635, in find_jar_iter
    (name_pattern, path_to_jar))
LookupError: Could not find stanford-ner.jar jar file at /home/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/stanford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar
```

I already set Environment variables in pycharm ide to 
CLASSPATH = /home/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/stanford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz;/home/PycharmProjects/Stanford-NER-Python/stanford/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar

I am using nltk version 3.2.1
python 2.7
ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345866/610569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I got it.
The location for stanford_classifier and stanford_ner_path were wrong and need to pass first two arguments in StandfordNERTagger() no need of ascii.