# Setting several corenlp_options in the StanfordDependencyParser with NLTK, Python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to set several options for the StanfordDependencyParser that I am using with NLTK:

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "path/to/stanford-parser-3.9.1-models.jar"
sdp = StanfordDependencyParser('path/to/stanford-parser-3.9.1-models.jar', corenlp_options=['-retainTmpSubcategories', '-originalDependencies'])
```

However, I get

```
raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11\\bin\\java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', '\\stanford-parser.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser', '-model', 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz', '-sentences', 'newline', '-outputFormat', 'conll2007', '-encoding', 'utf8', ['-retainTmpSubcategories', '-originalDependencies'], 'C:\\Users\\...']
```

(I removed some of the paths to make it clearer.)

If I only use

```
sdp = StanfordDependencyParser('path/to/stanford-parser-3.9.1-models.jar', corenlp_options=['-retainTmpSubcategories'])
```

or

```
sdp = StanfordDependencyParser('path/to/stanford-parser-3.9.1-models.jar', corenlp_options=['-originalDependencies'])
```

it works well...

I also looked at [the nltk code](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/stanford.html), the _execute function which is used to compute the commande line

```
def _execute(self, cmd, input_, verbose=False):
    encoding = self._encoding
    cmd.extend(['-encoding', encoding])
    if self.corenlp_options:
        cmd.append(self.corenlp_options)
```

Does this mean that I can only put 1 single option in the corenlp_options argument??

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Avoid that, use this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/51981566#51981566

Answer (score 0):

I kept on looking for a solution but it seems that there is no 'simple' one.
The solution I have found and that worked for me, is to directly modify stanford.py file in the nltk\parse\ folder. I replaced

```
cmd.append(self.corenlp_options)
```

with

```
cmd.extend(self.corenlp_options)
```

and no more exception raised although I doubt this is the best thing to do...