# Stanford POS Tagger raise error when I "tag" string

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying to run this code

```py
from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
st = StanfordPOSTagger('/home/username/Documents/stanford-tagger-4.0.0/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger', '/home/username/Documents/stanford-tagger-4.0.0/stanford-postagger-4.0.0.jar', encoding='utf8')
st.tag('Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network')
```

Error:

```sh
raise OSError("Java command failed : " + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['/usr/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', '/home/username/Documents/stanford-tagger-4.0.0/stanford-postagger-4.0.0.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model', '/home/username/Documents/stanford-tagger-4.0.0/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger', '-textFile', '/tmp/tmpmtz_fn09', '-tokenize', 'false', '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

Comment: Don't use the `nltk.tag.StanfordPOSTagger` use https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981566/610569

Comment: I replaced Stanford PosTagger to spaCy